# Ampersand (&) in WPF c# datagrid bind with database table

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

i cannot bind the table name in datagrid.
its not accepting the ampersand (&) table name in xaml.

here is the code.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="TOTAL_DATAGRID" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" ColumnWidth="80" Margin="54,113,62,114"> <DataGrid.Columns> <DataGridTextColumn Header="Kiln_TotalKWh" Binding="{Binding Energy_KILN_HOUR_Total_kiln&cooler_KWH_Value}" Width="80" /> < /DataGrid.Columns> </DataGrid>
```

Comment: share your code please

Comment: use `&amp;` instead of `&`

Comment: yes i have tried this buts its not working

Comment: {Binding Energy_KILN_HOUR_Total_kiln&cooler_KWH_Value} this is the line . when i add &amp; between kiln and cooler_KWH it block the cooler_KWH

Comment: Show the viewmodel or the source you are binding to.

Comment: @codelahiru this is the code

    <DataGrid x:Name="TOTAL_DATAGRID" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False"
      CanUserDeleteRows="False" ColumnWidth="80" Margin="54,113,62,114">
            <DataGrid.Columns> 
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Kiln_TotalKWh" Binding="{Binding Energy_KILN_HOUR_Total_kiln&cooler_KWH_Value}" Width="80" />

 < /DataGrid.Columns> </DataGrid>

Comment: Binding Path is to link XAML with the corresponding ViewModel Property. You can't need an ampersand there.

Comment: @MachineLearning Im binding the database with the datagrid in wpf c#

Comment: @NabeelKhan post the code where you are doing that

Comment: @NabeelKhan in a follow-up question

Comment: @MachineLearning  im using simple c# wpf. im showing the database value in the datagrid . im using Linq to connect the datagrid with the database. so in the datagrid xaml im binding the datagrid column with the database table column.

Comment: @MachineLearning but the problem is that the database table column has the name "Energy_KILN_HOUR_Total_kiln&cooler_KWH_Value" and because of the "&" in the name the datagrid binding "<DataGridTextColumn Header="Kiln_TotalKWh" Binding="{Binding Energy_KILN_HOUR_Total_kiln&cooler_KWH_Value}" Width="80" />" is  not accepting it.

Comment: @NabeelKhan if what you are doing is like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/362436/Data-binding-in-WPF-DataGrid-control) then you can rename the name in the select with the AS keyword

Comment: @MachineLearning i cannot change it in the database because i have to change it in many places. so please is there any way.

Comment: Not the database but this select to fill the datagrid

Comment: @MachineLearning sir i have also tried this method too. but also didn't work because the binding in xmal is the same.

Comment: Thank you @MachineLearning it work.......thank you very much

Comment: @NabeelKhan welcome, it would be nice if you can accept my answer (I'll update it with my above comment if it was helpful for you)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace ampersand with `&amp;` in XAML

**update from comments**

Binding Path is to link XAML with the corresponding ViewModel Property. You can't need an ampersand there.

If what you are doing is like [databinding using database](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/362436/Data-binding-in-WPF-DataGrid-control) then you can rename the column name in the select with the `AS` keyword

Comment: {Binding Energy_KILN_HOUR_Total_kiln&cooler_KWH_Value} this is the line . when i add &amp; between kiln and cooler_KWH it block the cooler_KWH

Comment: its not accepting the database table name
"Energy_KILN_HOUR_Total_kiln&cooler_KWH_Value"
because of the & in the name.

Comment: this is the code <DataGrid x:Name="TOTAL_DATAGRID" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" ColumnWidth="80" Margin="54,113,62,114"> <DataGrid.Columns> <DataGridTextColumn Header="Kiln_TotalKWh" Binding="{Binding Energy_KILN_HOUR_Total_kiln&cooler_KWH_Value}" Width="80" /> < /DataGrid.Columns> </DataGrid>

Comment: It's  `Energy_KILN_HOUR_Total_kiln&amp;cooler_KWH_Value` in XAML. The *database name* has nothing to do with either XAML or the ViewModel